# Query returns empty row

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns empty row with null value for all fields instead of returning 0 rows. I think Min is the problem, once I remove it, it start returning 0 rows. How I could fix it without changing the result of the query?

```
select *,min(STR_TO_DATE(concat(slot_date, ' ' , sec_to_time(from_time)),  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')) next_available_slot 
from  appt_available_slots 
where country_id = 1 
and   city_id = 1 
and   spec_id= 1 
and company_id = ifnull (NULLIF(2, 0), company_id) 
and slot_date ='2017-04-02' 
order by from_time ;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your query? Why do you need the `min()` part?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis to get the next available time, the closest time and date

Comment: And how do you specify "next available time"? Anyway, if you think you have lost your problem don't bother explaining to me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a single row, you should use `LIMIT 1`, not put a `MIN()` in the `SELECT` list.

```
select *, STR_TO_DATE(concat(slot_date, ' ' , sec_to_time(from_time)),  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') next_available_slot
from  appt_available_slots
where country_id = 1 
and   city_id = 1 
and   spec_id= 1 
and company_id = ifnull (NULLIF(2, 0), company_id) 
and slot_date ='2017-04-02' 
order by from_time
limit 1
```

Comment: but in this way, it returns many rows instead of one row when i it find data http://i.imgur.com/yLRlWPs.png

Comment: If you only want one row, use `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: In your original query, it returned the minimum in `next_slot`, and then a random row that matched the conditions.

Comment: order by from_time will return min time in the selected date. thanks for help.. I get it